# I just do not understand how this code is able to calculate factorial of the given numbers

Tags: c#, recursion

```
using System;
namespace CalculatorApplication
{
   class NumberManipulator
   {
      public int factorial(int num)
      {
         /* local variable declaration */
         int result;
         if (num == 1)
         {
            return 1;
         }
         else
         {
            result = factorial(num - 1) * num;
            return result;
         }
      }

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         NumberManipulator n = new NumberManipulator();
         //calling the factorial method
         Console.WriteLine("Factorial of 6 is : {0}", n.factorial(6));
         Console.WriteLine("Factorial of 7 is : {0}", n.factorial(7));
         Console.WriteLine("Factorial of 8 is : {0}", n.factorial(8));
         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

so i know it has to do with the function being a recursion but how is the code able to know when to keep multiplying the integers less than 6 in order to find the factorial. Also how does the code know when to stop multiplying when it reaches 6. If this was in a loop i could fully understand how this would be possible but with no loop i just do not understand.

I'm still in the tutorial of learning c#, if you can please try to keep it as simple as possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Learn how to debug code: set a breakpoint and step through line by line so you understand how it works.

Comment: look at that `if` statement. when you reach `num = 1` it will return 1. it does not reach 6. it goes from 6 to 1.

Comment: You're thinking about it in the wrong direction. The method multiplies from 6 down to 1, the base condition. I should think the minus in `factorial(num - 1)` is a good hint of that.

Comment: Ian Mercer ---- what do you mean?

Comment: Oh, i now see. Thank you M.kazem and Zong Zheng.

Comment: SO is generally about code _you_ have written

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's step through `factorial(6)`.

What's `factorial(6)`? `factorial(5) * 6`.

What's `factorial(5)`? `factorial(4) * 5`.

What's `factorial(4)`? `factorial(3) * 4`.

What's `factorial(3)`? `factorial(2) * 3`.

What's `factorial(2)`? `factorial(1) * 2`.

What's `factorial(1)`? `1`.

You then just go backward from there and you'll arrive at your answer:

`factorial(6)` = `1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6`.